# How do I make 2 labels add together with each other?

Tags: xcode, uibutton, uilabel, ibaction, iphone-sdk-4.1

Hi I'm kinda new to Xcode and I'm trying to make an app where you press a button and the number will go up; and I have 2 buttons and 2 labels.  I've got it to where the 2 labels will count up, but now I'm wanting the numbers from both labels to add together and show in a different label.  Is there any line I can add to the buttons to make them just count up in the other label as well or do I need to have a separate action and/or button?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Straight up:

```
int sum = [[label1 text] intValue] + [[label2 text] intValue];
label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sum];
```

Should work, just make sure to replace the pointers I used with the ones you're using.

Answer (score 0):

esqew's answer would do the trick, but the format specifier is incorrect.

If the variable `sum` is in fact an `int` ...

> label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", sum];

should be:

> label3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"**%d**", sum];

`%@` is for Objective-C objects, an `int` is not an Objective-C object.

Reference:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html